# Get filename in Dynamics Ax

Tags: list, iterator, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I need to extract a file name from complete path and I see it strange that I when I split the path, I need to iterate through the list to get the file name. Why can't I just get the value simply by calling `myList(3)` as in DotNet, instead of having to instantiate an iterator, then loop through the records.

Here is my code;

```
 List strlist=new List(Types::String); 
 strlist = strSplit(CompletePath, @"\");
```

After doing this I should have a list of all the different parts.
Is there any simple form to read the list, like `FileName = strlist[2];` instead of having to do the below;

```
iterator = new ListIterator(strlist);
while(iterator.more())
{
FileName = iterator.value();
if (_Value == "myFile")
{
 _NotFound=boolean::false;
}
```

Here again, if at that very moment, I don't know the file name, how do I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`System.IO.Path::GetFileName(CompletePath)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename) or [`System.IO.Path::GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension).

Answer (score 7):

```
Global::fileNameSplit(fileName)
```

returns a container [path, file name, extension]

Should be used over the .NET methods recommended by Matej.

Comment: Although just one call will not have much of an impact, using the X++ code will have better performance than using .NET